# Node-postgres.js результат запросов

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Например, есть такой код:

```
let text = 'UPDATE users SET role = ($1) WHERE token = ($2)';
let values = [role, token];
client.query(text,values);
       .then(res => {
           console.log(res.rows[0]);
           // Undefined
        })
       .catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
        })
```

И есть такой

```
let text = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE token = ($1)';
let values = [token];
client.query(text, values);
       .then(res => {
           console.log(res.rows[0]);
           // Какой-то объект, если есть в базе
        })
       .catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
        })
```

Возможно ли получить новый объект из результата запроса UPDATE подобно запросу SELECT?

Comment: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.5/dml-returning

Comment: Попробуйте вывести в консоль не res.rows[0], а res. Наверняка там будет какая-то информация о количестве измененных строк, айдишники измененных записей и прочая служебная информация.

Comment: @Mike опубликуйте как ответ.

Comment: @Mike прав. И да, опубликуйте как ответ.